# Connecting to my Tacx Neo 2T with Python via BLE, specifically using the Cycling Speed and Cadence Profile (CSC)

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I own a Tacx Neo 2T smart trainer and since it seems to support a generic BLE protocol I, for now, want to be able to

1. read the information that lets me calculate cadence
2. read the information that lets me calculate power
3. set the resistance level

For now, I'm really focusing on point 1. I know Python, I'm no stranger to coding but I have no experience with any of that BLE stuff.

I tried to connect with Pycycling which seems to be just the right thing. https://github.com/zacharyedwardbull/pycycling

This is what I have done so far:
I used an example to discover my trainer. This works, using bleak.
I  unsuccessfully tried to use the pycycling ftms = FitnessMachineService(client) which gives me the info that a characteristic 00002ad6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is not supported. Does this mean my trainer is not supported at all? The online info suggests that it does support this. Using this would (obviously) be my preferred method of working with the device.

Comment: Does your device have the characteristic with the uuid 00002ad6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb? Maybe check using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)